# How can I use these partitions to install fedora 20

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation

I want to install Fedora 20 from a full DVD (not live) on a new computer, with as much software as I can; so, during the set up for the installation, I tick all the repositories offered and then find that I need more space than is available. The machine was partitioned by the vendor, and Windows XP3 installed, so I will use a dual boot. I think the partitions he left me with are biased by his disdain for, or ignorance of, Linux.

I include a picture of the partitions from Windows on this machine; the C: partition is only 5% full, so it should cover the little I will use it for. So my question is: please, how do I make the rest available for Linux? I don't fully understand the jargon around partitions, in Linux or Windows, so I am extremely nervous about getting it wrong and losing Windows entirely. Needless to say I have aborted all my attempts at installing F20 so far.

It may be that I could use the repositories on the DVD after installation, but would I not then come up against the same space problem?

(Following on from @Anthon's comment) If, in Windows, I delete partitions E: and F: ( I have no data on them), will that affect my use of the Linux and Windows in the remaining partitions, until I install a new Fedora in place of the existing one, and then will the deleted partitions be automatically be included into Linux? How will I recognise them, if necessary, in the list during installation? Please forgive my fussy ignorance, I always get to a point in an attempt at installation, where there is something that I do not understand, even with the help of the installation instructions viewed on my laptop, and have to abort and start again, so I want to be fully prepared for these dangerous actions.

[image: Windows partions]

Comment: Is the title a typo asking about F12?

Comment: I wonder why your question is about Fedora 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since partition `E:` is, and partition and `F:` is almost empty, you should (under Windows) move what data you need that is on `F:` to `C:` and then delete the `E:` and `F:` partitions.

That way you create space for a 350Gb+ partition for Linux, which I think should be enough for any DVD install.

Comment: Thank you Anthon, I will do that, but I would please like reassurance as asked in  my newly edited question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realise that my comment would come up before I finished editing the question. Thank you for your close attention to my problem, very much appreciated.

Comment: @HarryWeston I am not familiar with the F20 installer. I am used to Ubuntu asking me if I want the whole disk, or just the free space or do a manual install. I invariably install manually, which means I know exactly which partitions I delete, then I create the partitions I need and let the system install.

Comment: Thanks again, I will do more research, try another install, and maybe come back again if I have to.

Comment: You partitioning program probably talks about `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4` which should be C:, D: and E: respectively (not 100% sure, this is based on the layout Windows provide, **check the sizes** and compare them with those in your image, before deleting/installing anything). Do you have a 500Gb+ drive on which you could do a backup first?

Comment: I had everything backed up before I bought the new PC, and the little work I have wished to keep since I have emailed to myself. I took a deep breath, and deleted partitions E: and F:, now windows is still ok, but Linux won't boot up. I will install Fedora 20 tomorrow. Again thanks for your continued help.

Comment: I have now installed Fedora 20 ok in the 375Gb space created by these deletions, problem solved, thank you for the help.

Comment: @HarryWeston Great. Try to come back here every once in a while; maybe you find a question where you can help some else, and thus close the circle.